# How to Sort ArrayList according to another list

Tags: android

I am making a Cab booking Application..In which i am sending push notification on driver side...i want to send pushnotification to the driver who have done minimum jobs.....
I have two lists...One is getting Jobs column from database and second is getting ObjectIds from database ObjectIds are in String and Jobs are in Integers....

I have sorted List of Jobs(Integers) in Ascending order using Collections.sort(jobs);

but now i want the objectIds list sorted according to the Jobs list...

for example:

This is my Jobs list before sorting:

[11 , 23 , 1 , 5 , 8]

This is my ObjectIds list :

[Rx3sh3BWO4 , P9m1hnWo7L , 71K6AkJOo3 , yjLhP0zKKG , 5UffHYiwlk]

When i sort Jobs list

[1,5,8,11,23]

but now i want the Object Ids that is related to 1 as in 0 index of ObjectIds list...

How to sort List ObjectIds comparing to Jobs list????

Comment: Is there a need to keep JobID and ObjectIDs separate or do the belong together?

Answer (score 0):

Use [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and add key as your ObjectID and values as jobId ( or vice versa as per your requirements)

and If you want to sorting then you can also use ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a Map instead of lists?
e.g.

```
Map<Integer, String>
```

That way you can say

```
map.get(11)
```

which will return you the String 'Rx3sh3BWO4'

For sorting you could use a SortedMap which will keep itself sorted however you define, or you could get a Set of the keys using Map.keySet() and copy it to a List (or a SortedSet) which you can then sort before iterating through.

Note that in general Maps do not guarantee to keep their order - a LinkedHashMap keeps the order you insert and a SortedMap re-sorts its keys into the order you define.

Alternatively, keeping two Lists, you could make your own (ugly) sort method which makes a clone of the Jobs List before it's sorted, then makes a new List for the ObjectIds and iterates round the newly-sorted Jobs list looking up the index of each ObjectId in the clone and adding the ObjectId to the new List. That's not very pretty though, I'd go with a Map.